# try-runtime polkadot version 36 .. execution flag removed

Tags: try-runtime

we try to execute try-runtime command in this way

```
cargo run --release --features=try-runtime,mangata-rococo try-runtime --chain=public-testnet --execution=Native on-runtime-upgrade live --uri wss://roccoco-testnet-collator-01.mangatafinance.cloud:443
```

but we got an error that

```
Found argument '--execution' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

It looks like this execution flag was removed; now, by default, it is only wasm.

When we remove the execution flag, we need to specify the runtime flag which, based on the substrate repo, is the path to the wasm blob ?

[Substrate docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/try-runtime/) is not up to date I think.

Can you help us what is the correct way to execute try-runtime.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the CLI version that you are using? The [documentation of the latest try-runtime CLI](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/index.html) is a good resource, unfortunately the Substrate docs are out of date with the newer version of try-runtime CLI as there has been a few releases recently.

> When we remove the execution flag, we need to specify the runtime flag which, based on the substrate repo, is the path to the wasm blob ?

In order to obtain the runtime wasm binary, you can compile the Substrate node (with the runtime changes to test) with `try-runtime` feature enabled. Then, you can copy the wasm binary located under `./target/release/wbuild/node-with-tryruntime.wasm` to another folder and use as an input to the `try-runtime` command.

You should be able to execute the command above once you pass the `--runtime node-with-tryruntime.wasm` param.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution. It is working.